# Safe database synchronisation mysql

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

We have a central server which only receive data from other servers (currently, the central server will be used only to show the reports and the graphics).

So, we have multiple installations located at different places (not on the same network) on which the data will be written (small server)

We need to take those added/modified/deleted data on each server and update the central server with those datas.

We've already took a look at SymmetricDS which

What we have thought to do is, set a flag in the database for each row (added/modified/deleted) that are not already synchronised and create a query with REPLACE INTO for each row with the flag set.

Is this the good way to do that? Or, do you have any other idea to do it?

UPDATE :

not all client will have access to an internet connection. So those servers won't be synchronised until they have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think triggers work best in your case. Unless you want the do the update of everything at once then your solution will do

Comment: I forgot to mention this : not all client will have access to an internet connection. So those servers won't be synchronised until they have it. Will it work with a trigger or it will crashed if we have not connection to the central server database?

Comment: As far as i Know, triggers are executed on the spot, either before or after the query.

Answer (score 0):

Having done something similar, here are a few tips;

- Consider using UUID for identifiers, this will allow you to merge data from multupple sources without clashing, if this is not possible auto increment has offset, and increment amount, so for isntance you can have an increment of 100 (if less than 100 systems out there), and db 1 starts at offset 1, db 2 at offset 2, at least all your offsite databases will have different id's
- Use soft deletes, have 'is_deleted' flag on each table, simply exclude these from your queries or results
- Ensure any table you want to sync has an 'updated' field created with `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
- An import procedure will go something like this

  - backup remote tables
  - restore to temporary database
  - Get the max('udpated') time from your temp db, save this for the next import
  - Run a replace along the lines `REPLACE INTO currentdb.mytbl SELECT tempdb.mytbl WHERE updated > {previous max(updated)}`

I've used this procedure to keep internationally located databases up to date with very few issues.

Comment: I've already have the 2 first points, but I'm not sure what you mean with your last point. What are the remote tables? You do this part on the central server? If yes, that means that you have to connect from the central server to all differents locations?